# Correct parameters for MFCopyImage?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to create an IMFSample from a CImage so that I that I can encode a video from a series of images using a SinkWriter. Microsoft has a sample of how to do this with a DWORD array (instead of a CIMage) here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819477(v=vs.85).aspx . Doing this involves using `MFCopyImage()`, but I am getting an ACCESS VIOLATION when calling this function, so I may be passing in the wrong parameters. I am new to C++.

Working from their sample, this is what I've got:

```
CImage *img = LoadImage();

IMFSample *pSample = NULL;
IMFMediaBuffer *pBuffer = NULL;

const LONG cbWidth = img->GetBPP() / 8 * img->GetWidth();
const DWORD cbBuffer = cbWidth * img->GetHeight();

BYTE *pData = NULL;
HRESULT hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(cbBuffer, &pBuffer);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pBuffer->Lock(&pData, NULL, NULL);
}

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = MFCopyImage(
        pData,                     
        cbWidth,                    
        (BYTE*)img->GetBits(),   
        cbWidth,                   
        cbWidth,                    
        img->GetHeight()
        ); // ACCESS VIOLATION HERE!
}
if (pBuffer)
{
    pBuffer->Unlock();
}
```

Anyone know why this gets me an ACCESS VIOLATION ? Am I passing in the right values, especially for the stride? Based on this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb970554(v=vs.85).aspx , it was not clear to me what exactly this parameter is supposed to be.

Update Dec 11: Changed code sample with corrections provided by @cha and @roman-r. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you checked that the image is loaded OK after you call CImage *img = LoadImage()?

Comment: I can see a small problem. GetBPP() returns number of bits per pixel. Both MFCopyImage and MFCreateMemoryBuffer use bytes. So, my guess is that you need to initialise cbWidth like this: const LONG cbWidth = img->GetBPP() / 8 * img->GetWidth();

Comment: I think the image has loaded OK, because if I call .Save(_T("foo.jpg")) on it, I can see that the resulting image is good.

Comment: Ah, good point about GetBPP() @cha. Unfortunately, I still get the error after that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access violation is caused by wrong arguments. The API just hits memory beyond either source or destination buffers.

You are already aware of `GetBPP` issue, which is not small but severe (you should have your code snippet updated respectively).

Another issue is the last `MFCopyImage` argument. It's height, not width. Since width is typically smaller you are likely to have a buffer overrun.

Additionally you are assuming minimal stride. Effectively you might have a larger one. In this case you would see a skew effect on the copied image and not access violation.

Comment: You're right, I'll update the code sample. I tried running the code with both of these changes, but I still get the same error. For the stride, how I determine what that should be set to?

Comment: Stride is unlikely to be a problem here.

Comment: FYI, `CImage::GetPitch` is the stride for your source image.

Comment: Changing the stride to img->GetPitch() got rid of the access violation. Thanks!